# gsutil to copy all files and create a subdirectory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have 4 files xxxxx.xlsx in this directory:

```
/var/tmp/dagxxxxx/2019-08-10/xxxxx.xlsx
```

I want to copy them over to:

```
gs://reports_dev/2019
```

Using gsutil cp -r the final gcs path should be like(with all 4 files):

```
gs://reports_dev/2019/2019-08-10/xxxxx.xlsx
```

I tried different combination of cp and -r like:

```
gsutil cp -r /var/tmp/dagxxxxx/2019-08-10/** gs://reports_dev/2019
```

but couldn't get the desired path in gcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the trailing Asterisks, `-r` already means recursive, this should work:

```
gsutil cp -r /var/tmp/dagxxxxx/2019-08-10/ gs://reports_dev/2019
```

If you append a forward slash `/` to your source, it will copy the folder to your destination, if you don't, it will copy the Content of your source to your destination.

Comment: This is actually not working to not copy the folder to the destination, i have tried with and without the `/` at the end and it copies the source folder anyway.

Comment: @Tom3652 I think that happens because you already have content in your destination. Then it will copy the folder in your destination, so it will not overwrite what you already have there.

Comment: Yees thanks for the explanation, i have found a way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519118/how-to-not-copy-source-folder-gsutil-bucket-to-bucket to avoid this :)