# How to not copy source folder gsutil bucket to bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I simply would like to copy recursively the `content` of one of my bucket directories to another bucket.

When i run :

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my_first_bucket/source_dir/ gs://my_second_bucket/target_dir
```

I would like to not find `source_dir` inside `target_dir` but only its content.

I have also tried (not working) to remove the `/` at the end of the `source_dir` path :

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my_first_bucket/source_dir gs://my_second_bucket/target_dir
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#wildcard-characters). Try the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r 'gs://my_first_bucket/source_dir/*' gs://my_second_bucket/target_dir
```

Do make sure you add the single quotes around the source bucket URL. Checkout the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#potentially-surprising-behavior-when-using-wildcards) for more information on that.